# Change CKEDITOR bold default color

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I would like set a default color in the tag **< strong >** in ckeditor.

I tried to set

```
<strong style='color:rgb(255, 140, 0)'>
```

But when you change the color of a bold element the ckeditor creates a span involving the strong and only shows the strong color

```
<span style="color:#008000"><strong style='color:rgb(255, 140, 0)'></span>
```

**How can I put a default color in a bold element?**

Comment: not getting your question can you explain the "But when you change the color of a bold element the ckeditor creates a span involving the strong and only shows the strong color"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use an external CSS for this:

```css
/* default color */
strong {
    color: rgb(255, 140, 0);
}

/*
if parent span has inline style with color definition,
inherit it instead
*/
span[style*="color"] > strong {
    color: inherit;
}
```